# Efficient way to find a similar set in a list of sets

Tags: algorithm, sorting, similarity, nearest-neighbor

I have an array of sets which can be very large in size containing sets or tuples of 3 numbers between 0 and 1.

My aim is to find which of these is most similar to a new given set, similarity is defined by the sum of the absolute difference between the numbers in 2 given sets, this should be minimized. For example, the total "score" of `(1, 0, 1)` and `(1, 0, 0)`
would be |1 - 1| + |0 - 0| + |1 - 0| = 1

The obvious solution would be to step through such an array and return the minimum, but this becomes inefficient should I want to perform it multiple times. My hope was there would be some nice way to sort it such as a hash meaning "similar" sets get put together, then a binary search may be used to efficiently find a good match for a new set.

Example:

let `s = [(0.5, 0.8, 0.3), (0, 0, 0), (1, 0.2, 0.75), (1, 1, 1), (0.6, 0.6, 0)]`

if given a set `(0.8, 0, 1)` would give the absolute sum differences of:

```
[1.8, 1.8, 0.65, 1.2, 1.8]
```

so based on this we can deduce the most similar set to `(0.8, 0, 1)` would be `(1, 0.2, 0.75)` in what can hopefully be worked out in some other way in less than linear time.

Thank you for any responses, or points in the right direction

Comment: You may want to check out K-D trees: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree

Comment: Generally this is a well-known problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search with many exact (including the k-d-trees and its generalization [BSP trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning)) and approximate methods.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that both of these have no exact solutions? (which is okay - approximate in my case is absolutely fine) if there is such an exact algorithm, which would that be?

Comment: @NightShade, I'm not sure what you mean by "both" in your comment. The problem clearly have an exact solution because you can just check every point in the set. The real question is: can we find the best solution in better time in all the cases? AFAIU, the answer to this question is no, you can't. So you have a trade-off between finding the best solution mostly in something like `O(log(N))` but sometimes taking `O(N)` in the worst cases that still can happen and using some approximate method that is guaranteed to always be better than `O(N)` but is not guaranteed to always find the best.

Comment: @SergGr to be honest, I have no idea what I meant at the time either, but this is a good explanation. In this case I think I may use a `O(log(N))` approach that finds a good estimate, however I came across [This algorithm in this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/14384) which seems to find an exact solution in good time by partitioning, or some divide and conquer technique for you or anyone else interested. I can see in worst case it would still work O(N) but guess in average case would still be efficient

Comment: @NightShade, this answer refers exactly to the "k-d-trees" that both I and Primusa referred too. This is a good algorithm in the first class: it does find the exact answer and **_usually_** (i.e. for most of the data) it does so in good time but there are some rare "pathological" bad cases when it does `O(n)` anyway. This is what the "Average" and "Worst case" columns in the description in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). Depending on your real data this might be or not be a problem for you.

Comment: Another approach is to use locality-sensitive hash functions (such as [SimHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SimHash)) to quickly estimate the similarity between sets.